# Swing component listening to itself vs inner classes

Tags: java, swing, listener, inner-classes, anonymous-class

I just got some bad feedback on a uni project and need some impartial clarification;

Can anyone explain when I should use (anonymous) inner listener classes vs components that listen to themselves? (a vs b)

a)

```
public class myButton extends JButton {

    public myButton() {

        addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // handling code...

            }
        });
    }
}
```

b)

```
public class myButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {

    public myButton() {

        addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        // handle the event
    }
}
```

Thanks guys,
Mitch

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: good teacher, assuming s/he rejected both :-)

Comment: Assuming your code as an example (extending JButton doesnt make sense to me, but lets say it could be any class), did anyone ever answered what are the benefits of implements vs inner class?

Answer (score 4):

c)

```
JButton myButton = new JButton(); 
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        // handling code...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

For cases where you have multiple buttons with different behavior it is more convenient to assign a separate anonymous class for each button, you can still implement ActionListener in your class and handle the event according to the source:

```
void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    if (e.getSrouce() == button1)
    { ... }
    else if (e.getSource() == button2)
    { ... }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: unrelated to the question, but I seem to be on a quest :-) that's procedural style, so don't.

Comment: I agree. As I wrote, it is more convenient to use anonymous / separate classes for this case, I just pointed out the meaning of implementing the ActionListener for all buttons in one class. And thanks for the comment.

Comment: I think the OP was trying to ask a question to which this is the answer, but I strongly agree with [@AndrewThompson's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5856145/253468).

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be a personal preference. Anyway I would always go for inner classes as a way to separate responsabilities and organizing the code.

In particular, they are the only way to use the Adapter classes (empty classes that already implement some particular Listener interfaces, so you only need to overwrite the methods you need and you do not need to provide an empty implementation of those that you do not need).

Answer (score 1):

The point is that when you declare your `myButton` class to implement `ActionListener`, you increase its visible API (ie add a new public `actionPerformed()` method, freely callable by any code that holds a reference to a `myButton`).

Since you probably don't want "`actionPerformed`" to be part of `myButton` API, you ought to use an inner class, that will preserve the public API of `myButton`.

Note that Swing classes are full of bad examples like that where the public methods are explicitly commented as "*implementation detail, do not call directly*", very bad design decision actually.